# What is the outcome of this circuit?

Tags: quantum-gate

What would be the outcome of this circuit?

[image]

Answer (score 4):

The outcome is $-i\left| 11 \right\rangle
$. Here is how I obtained it.

$$
\left| 01 \right\rangle \xrightarrow{\text{X}}
\left| 11 \right\rangle \xrightarrow{\text{Y}}
-i\left| 10 \right\rangle  \xrightarrow{\text{CNOT}}
-i\left| 11 \right\rangle  \xrightarrow{\text{SWAP}}
-i\left| 11 \right\rangle
$$

$X$ gate changes 0 to 1, and 1 to 0:

$$
X \left| 0 \right\rangle = \left| 1 \right\rangle 
\qquad
X \left| 1 \right\rangle = \left| 0 \right\rangle
$$

$Y$ gate also changes 0 to 1, and 1 to 0, but also changes the phase of the qubit:

$$
Y \left| 0 \right\rangle = i\left| 1 \right\rangle 
\qquad
Y \left| 1 \right\rangle = -i\left| 0 \right\rangle
$$

CNOT changes the second qubit if the first qubit is in $\left| 1 \right\rangle$ state and does nothing if the first qubit is in $\left| 0 \right\rangle$ state:

$$
CNOT \left| 00 \right\rangle = \left| 00 \right\rangle 
\qquad
CNOT \left| 01 \right\rangle = \left| 01 \right\rangle
$$

$$
CNOT \left| 10 \right\rangle = \left| 11 \right\rangle
\qquad
CNOT \left| 11 \right\rangle = \left| 10 \right\rangle
$$

SWAP gate changes the qubits, first qubit's state becomes the state of the second qubit and vice versa:

$$
SWAP \left| 00 \right\rangle = \left| 00 \right\rangle 
\qquad
SWAP \left| 01 \right\rangle = \left| 10 \right\rangle
$$

$$
SWAP \left| 10 \right\rangle = \left| 01 \right\rangle
\qquad
SWAP \left| 11 \right\rangle = \left| 11 \right\rangle
$$

Comment: what would be the input of this circuit and why?

Comment: The input is given in your example: in the picture after q[0] it is written | 0> and after q[1] it is written |1>. So, the input state is |0>|1> = |01>

Comment: and for that particular input state (|01>) the circuit produces -i|11> state

Comment: I just applied the gates to the input state by taking into account that X|0> = |1>, Y|1> = -i|0>, CNOT |1> |0> = |1> |1> and SWAP |11> = |11>

Comment: I have edited the answer, hope now it is more clear how I obtained the result :)

Comment: Great Work .. @DavitKhachatryan

Comment: Thanks :) @Ba.Taj

Comment: "Y gate also changes 0 to 1, and 1 to 0, but also changes the phase of the qubit" Can you explain "PHASE OF THE QUBIT" for Y gate?

Comment: Yep, Here is the change of the phase for |0> state, which initial phase is equal to zero |0> = exp(i0)|0>. Y |0> = i |1> = exp(i pi/2) |1>. So the phase was 0 and it was changed to pi/2.

Comment: For an arbitrary state $Y \psi = Y \left( a \left| 0 \right\rangle + b \left|1 \right\rangle \right) = ia \left|1 \right\rangle - ib \left|0 \right\rangle = -i \left( b \left|0 \right\rangle -  a \left|1 \right\rangle \right) = e^{- \pi/2} \left( b \left|0 \right\rangle + e^{i \pi}  a \left|1 \right\rangle \right)$. The first exponent's phase is called the global phase that often we ignore it because it is unmeasurable and the second exponent's phase we can call the added phase to the qubit.